# How to switch between tabs in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, shortcut-keys

In Firefox or Chromium I use`ctrl+tab` (or `ctrl+shift+tab`) for this function.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The keyboard shortcuts for Nautilus are mapped in the `~/.config/nautilus/accels` file. From there I deduced that:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> is used to switch to next tab.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> is used to switch to previous tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is used to switch to first tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is used to switch to second tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is used to switch to third tab.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> is used to switch to tab 4.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> is used to switch to tab 5.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> is used to switch to tab 6.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> is used to switch to tab 7.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> is used to switch to tab 8.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd> is used to switch to tab 9.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> is used to switch to tab 10.

Comment: Nautilus 3.22 has no such file.

Comment: well 3.14.3 has ~/.config/nautilus/accels. But you just can't customize the keyboard shortucts.